# ERROR : Cannot modify Managed Object

Tags: community, managed-package, salesforce1-app

I'm trying to enable field history tracking for a certain custom field of a certain custom object.

The Custom field in which I am trying to enable this setting is of type LOOKUP whenever I try to do that I get an error as;

> Cannot modify managed object:
>
> entity=FieldAttributes, component=**********, field=BusinessStatus,
>   state=installed

I know this is a component of a managed package, is there a workaround for this?
`Field History Tracking` was enabled for the object as well

Comment: Are you getting this error during deployment or when doing manually from setup screen?

Comment: I am getting this error during deployment, there is no error while doing it manually from the setup screen.

Comment: You should be getting an error saying, old value and new value. Is that the case?

Comment: No, I do not get such error, the only error which I get is the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because the package vendor would have not enabled "Field history tracking" for the object you are enabling it.

You can request your package vendor to enable that for you. They can enable and then you can upgrade the package to allow you to enable it without issues.

Comment: Thankyou for the respone ."Field History tracking " for the object was enabled but still for some fields, I get that error and for some fields, I do not get it

Comment: What is the data type of that field?

Comment: The data type of the field is Lookup

Comment: Can you screenshot the error ? Also it is better to reach to vendor as well

Comment: @MohithShrivastava the error is exactly the one I mentioned I cannot screenshot it, I get the error during deployment. also, I am the vendor.